# How to convert GNU Gettext .po files to Qt's .ts files?

Tags: qt, localization, translation, gettext, po

Is there a tool to convert the translations in GNU Gettext `.po` format into Qt's native `.ts` format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [po2ts](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/ts2po) which is meant for exactly this task. It is part of the [Translate Toolkit](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/installation) which you can download for your appropriate platform.

Answer (score 14):

Today I [found](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Localization) that it could be done using the `lconvert` tool that comes with the Qt distribution and had already been present on my system.

So I simply did

```
lconvert -locations relative <file>.po -o <file>.ts
```

It also supports the backward conversion:

```
lconvert <file>.ts -o <file>.po
```